# Mocking custom exceptions in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, pytest

Most third-party Python libraries throw custom exceptions. Many of these  exceptions have their own dependencies and side effects. Consider, for example, the following situation:

```
class ThirdPartyException(BaseException):
    def __init__(self):
        print("I do something arcane and expensive upon construction.")
        print("Maybe I have a bunch of arguments that can't be None, too.")

    def state(self) -> bool:
        # In real life, this could be True or False
        return True
```

Let's say, moreover, that I absolutely have to handle this exception, and to do it, I need to look at the exception's state. If I want to write tests to examine the behavior when this exception is handled, I **must** have the ability to create a `ThirdPartyException`. But I may not even be able to figure out how, let alone how to do it cheaply.

If this weren't an `Exception` and I wanted to write tests, I would immediately reach for `MagicMock`. But I cannot figure out how to use `MagicMock` with an exception.

How do I test the error handling cases in the following code, ideally using `py.test`?

```
def error_causing_thing():
    raise ThirdPartyException() 

def handle_error_conditionally():
    try:
        error_causing_thing()
    exception ThirdPartyException as e:
        if state:
             return "Some non-error value"
        else:
             return "A different non-error value"
```

Comment: To be clear, is `ThirdPartException` something you don't have any control over, and you want `error_causing_thing` to raise one that has a specific state value?

Comment: Give the exception **instance** as the attribute or argument `side_effect` to the mock or to the `patch` call.

Comment: @chepner, yes. If `state` is boolean, I'll want to write two test cases to exercise how my function handles `ThirdPartyException`.

Comment: @KlausD., I'd like to avoid actually constructing `ThirdPartyException`. I tried to mock one with `spec=ThirdPartyException`, but I got an error that you can't raise anything that's not a subclass of `BaseException`. When I tried to patch as a mock, I got the same error. When I tried to patch as my own alternative exception,  it didn't get handled at all (because it wasn't recognized as an instance of `ThirdPartyException`).

Comment: It might be better to figure out how to make `error_causing_thing` raise the appropriate exception naturally.

Comment: @chepner, Interesting. In the wild, `error_causing_thing` is usually a call to a method from the third-party library. We could wrap the call in its own function and extract the state there, but that just kicks the can down the road: what if it gets `ThirdPartyException`'s interface wrong? It's better than nothing, but it seems like there *has* to be a way to do this for real. It's just such a common problem, and it's what mocks are for.

Comment: What I'm saying is to create an appropriate fixture in which `error_causing_thing` *naturally* raises the desired exception. For example, if you want to test code that raises a `KeyError` whose `args` attribute contains `"foo"`, you don't mock `KeyError`; you simply ensure that the appropriate object `d` doesn't *have* a key `"foo"`, at which point the correct exception is raised without having to mock the exception itself.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a stale question, and I am not using pytest, but I had a similar issue with unittest, and just found a solution that someone else may find helpful. I added a `patch` for my custom exception with `new` keyword having a value of any class that is a subclass of an `Exception` (or is the `Exception` class):

```
import unittest
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch
# ... other imports required for these unit tests

class MockCustomException(Exception):
    def state(self):
        return self.__class__.state_return_value

class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        custom_exception_patcher = patch(
            'path.to.CustomException',
            new=MockCustomException
        )
        custom_exception_patcher.start()                # start patcher
        self.addCleanup(custom_exception_patcher.stop)  # stop patch after test
    
    def test_when_state_true(self):
        MockCustomException.state_return_value = True
        self.assertEqual(handle_error_conditionally(), "Some non-error value")
    
    def test_when_state_false(self):
        MockCustomException.state_return_value = False
        self.assertEqual(handle_error_conditionally(), "A different non-error value")
```

This method can also be used on a per test basis, by using `patch` as a decorator or as a context manager:

```
# ... imports, etc
class MockCustomExceptionStateTrue:
     def state(self):
         return True

@patch('path.to.CustomException', new=MockCustomExceptionStateTrue)
def test_with_decorator_patch(self):
     self.assertEqual(handle_error_conditionally(), "Some non-error value")

def test_with_context_manager(self):
    
    class MockCustomException:
         def state(self):
            return True
    
    with patch('path.to.CustomException', new=MockCustomException):
         self.assertEqual(handle_error_conditionally(), "Some non-error value")
```

Hopefully this is helpful for someone!! After briefly looking through pytest docs, it looks like monkeypatching is similar to the unittest patch functionality